# How to display a default image in case the source does not exists in MvC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following code in loginpartial.cshtml file
Can anyone advice if there is a way to display a default image if the src does not exists?

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{   

    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">



        //in below image tab m Display user Uploaded image ,
        //wants to display default Image if no Image is present

        <img src="/user/RetrievePhoto/@ABC.Web.Session.LoginData.UserToken.UserId" alt="" class="profilePhotoSM" />@ABC.Web.Session.LoginData.UserToken.UserName <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
                }</li>
        </ul>
    </li>


}
else
{

    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "Register", "User", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class = "navLink" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Authentication", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "navLink" })</li>

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a default image to your web server i.e. `myDefaultImage.png`.
Add an `ImageName` and `Photo` properties to your model i.e.

```
public class AModel
{
   public string ImageName { get; set; }
   public string Photo { get { return ImageName == null ? "myDefaultImage.png" : ImageName; }}
}
```

Set the `ImageName` property from your controller if the image exists. The get in the `Photo` property will handle the default image if it is not set.

You can then show the src as follows:

```
src="/user/RetrievePhoto/@Model.Photo"
```